# My custom UITableViewCells are affecting the status of each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell with a UISwitch, a UIStepper and two labels inside.

When I run my app in the simulator, and the tableview lists each instance of this custom cell. I notice that when I toggle the switch in the first cell and increase it's stepper (affecting one label), the ninth cell is affected the same way.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *items = [self arrayForSection:indexPath.section];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    cell.notificationTitle.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I also have two sections in this tableview, and set the first one so that the selection style is off.

What is going on exactly and how to do I keep it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the part where you are creating the custom cell? Are you doing that or is it just that you've missed it out while pasting it here?

Try this (hope you're using a NIB file to create a custom cell):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *questionTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:questionTableIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    cell.notificationTitle.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it is linked to the prototype cell in the associated tableviewcontroller. Should I make a nib for this custom cell class?

Answer (score 1):

When you use this `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:questionTableIdentifier];` you are actually reusing a already made instance of your cell(if there is any to be reused else create a new one). UITableViews work this way in order to conserve memory. If you have a very large number of cells it will still only consume about the same amount of memory as if there were only enough to cover the screen. In order to fix your problem you need to keep the state of your cell's some other place then the cell itself. Maybe a data structure in your tableviewcontroller or viewcontroller. And then set the values when your tableview wants to display the cell.

If you go with the non reusable cells then you could do something like this.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *cells;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
        _cells = @[@[[[YourCell alloc] init],
                    [[YourCell alloc] init],
                    [[YourCell alloc] init]
                   ],
                   [@[[YourCell alloc] init],
                    [[YourCell alloc] init],
                    [[YourCell alloc] init]]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return _cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
}
```

Assuming you have 2 sections with 3 cells in each section.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking that a data structure associated for this cell would be necessary. I would test that out once my server is running in a few days.

Comment: Should I make a unique identifier for these cells then? I only need 10 to 15 of them.

Comment: Well if you want to use reusable cells you cant put the actual cells in a data structure but rater just the states of the cells. But if you  only have a small number of cells then it's actually much easier to not use reusable cells. I'll update my answer to illustrate what i mean.

Comment: Upon looking further, a data structure is indeed a better way to go about this. In the end every update made to a cell will just send a call to the server to update settings for the associated user. My view controller will just download content and update each cell. then will be called again to update changes on the server.